# Performance Analysis Of A Function

Tags: c++, performance

I have to call a function 100000 times in my program . if the argument passed to the function is 4 then it returns 5 if the argument passed is 5 it returns 4. I have the following  two function performing the same task one uses subtraction and other uses division operation .  I need the fastest code. Which one is the better and why .

```
int function1( int x)
{
   return 9-x;
}

int function2(int x )
{
   return 20/x;
}
```

Comment: On which language exactly? o.O Tagging more than one programming language is _generally_ bad way to tag a question. If you looking a faster code, you should explain first why this code is not fast as you want. And that's why your question belongs on [CodeReview.SE], not here.

Comment: What does it do if the argument is neither 4 nor 5?

Comment: That sounds like a very specific usage for a function... What are you really trying to do? (this sounds like an XY problem..), an `if/else` would be faster than both of these

Comment: @Sayse: It's unlikely that a branch would be faster, unless the input data is regular enough for branch prediction to be useful (and even then it's doubtful it would beat a single subtract).

Comment: Are you sure your use case deserves a function?

Comment: By far the biggest overhead will be in the calling of function. Why not `inline` it? I'd imagine that subtraction would be faster; but why not test this? But if you're having to optimise performance to this degree then you might need to consider hand-coded assembly. But you'll do well to beat optimised C and C++ until you're truly an expert.

Comment: @Sayse i dont know my boss told me to write a faster code . i wrote the the above code . now i  have to justify which one is really faster.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - Possibly, but even so I still think this is an XY problem

Comment: @arifhussainshigri - Your boss has asked you a pretty non-sensical question IMO. You need to decipher what this function is really attempting to do and address that. If he's testing you as to discovering how to test performance, then he is testing *you* and it is for you to research

Comment: Does your "boss" possess compelling evidence that the *specific* code this is replacing is indeed a choke point?  Compile to assembly, pull up the instructions and count up the clock cycles (yes, this will require some actual work with the chosen processor architecture manual).  And fyi, both of those are highly likely inlined, (they better be; the call-overhead would likely dwarf the actual opcodes these produce). Validate the findings with benchmarking, then type it all up in a pretty report (tables and graphs optional) and hand it back to your boss.

Comment: why people are  down voting this question  ..?????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you want to know about performance, measure.  I did:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int total = 0;
  int rep = atoi(argv[1]);
  for (int ii = 0; ii < rep; ++ii)
  {
    total += function1(4 + ii % 2);
  }

  std::cout << total << '\n';
}
```

This program alternates passing 4 and 5 to the function, with special care to avoid compile-time optimization of the number of iterations or elision of the entire computation.  Here are the results, computed on a pretty normal Intel x86_64 Linux box using `g++ -O3 -g -Wall`, `valgrind --tool=callgrind`, and finally `kcachegrind` for easy visualization of "Instruction read" counts in `main()`:

- `9 - x`: 345K
- `20/ x`: 1320K
- `x ^ 1`: 345K

If you prefer wall times, those are:

- `9 - x`: 0.48s
- `20/ x`: 4.7s
- `x ^ 1`: 0.48s

Given all that, stick with the subtraction version.

---

Finally, a note on what "Instruction read" means in the statistics from valgrind (thanks to "Iwillnotexist Idonotexist" for the comment):

> Instruction read is equal to the number of instructions fetched (and executed). This statistic breaks down and gives misleading results precisely around ultra-long instructions like division, and moreover ignores the processor's potential for superscalar execution and pipeline hazards.

Comment: clear analysis, and nice explanation. Note maybe that performance might depend on platform architecture?

Comment: I made the same mistake once of thinking Valgrind gives cycle counts. It does not. The statistic you report is `Ir`, which stands for _Instruction read_, and is equal to the number of instructions fetched (and executed). This statistic breaks down and gives misleading results precisely around ultra-long instructions like division, and moreover ignores the processor's potential for superscalar execution and pipeline hazards. In fact, for a long time I had understated one of my own numerical codes' speed by a factor of 1.7x, precisely because we had so much ILP.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: thanks for that, you're right and I have re-worded that part to be more correct.  Most people may be more interested in the wall time measurements which I added a few minutes ago, which in agreement with what you said, reflect much slower execution of the division than the subtraction, even beyond what valgrind shows.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Admittedly though, Valgrind generally gives an accurate breakdown of costs and is a good-to-excellent estimate when all instructions cost about the same. By the way, you may absolutely incorporate my disembodied comment into your answer - fewer jumps for the future reader.

Answer (score 2):

This depends (or might depend) on many factors:

- what is your code supposed to do when you get another argument than 4 or 5
- your machine, compiler, optimisation,...

anyway the easiest way to check which one is more performant is to add a small timer, and perform each of your functions a number of times; like this:

```
struct timeval t1, t2;
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

int i, a;
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
    a += function1(4);
    }

gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
printf("Time elapsed: %li µs\n", (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000 + t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec);
```

**warning** if you use code optimization (gcc -O2 or something like that), it might optimize out unused variables. That's why I do: `a +=`... so the compiler thinks the output is used...

Answer (score 0):

Use Bit manipulation.

Sweet and simple

```
int x=5;
cout<< (x^1);  //output 4

int x=4;
cout<< (x^1);  //output 5
```

you can check here http://ideone.com/tA1SrI

Comment: Who downvotes this proposal and why? It's certainly at least as quick as the original operations. And, at least, if anybody downvotes it, a comment indicating the problem would be useful.

Comment: Did you profile this? Do you think writing to stdout is faster than returning from a function?

Comment: The point is the xor, not the way to present the result. I also think that a function would be more comparable with the original question, thus more useful. But, anyway, it's a good hint to use xor instead of minus or division.

Comment: @HansKlünder And where is the evidence that it is faster than anything? Also, the question asks which of two options given is faster.

Comment: @juanchopanza it is obviously faster than multiply and addition.no?

Comment: There is no compelling reason why XOR should be any faster than SUB.

Comment: @Shan No, it is not obvious at all.

Comment: It depends on the processor. Some processors have instructions that include small operands. 1 is smaller than 9. Thus it's a good idea to use the smaller operand, increasing the chance that that might save to work to store 9 in a register. It's not at all obvious that this is an advantage, and maybe it is not, but using xor1 ist a good strategy not to miss that possible advantage.

Comment: This is not faster than subtraction.  See my answer for proof (on amd64).

Comment: I looked into 3 instruction sets: intel, ARM and PowerPC. It looks like for intel xor and minus are equal, for ARM minus is faster, for PowerPC xor is faster. That said, I still think the proposal to use xor can be quite valuable, depending on which processor will be used.

Comment: @HansKlünder Thanks .could you please show me how did you check this? any link or on local?

Comment: Just google for xor, immediate and either intel or ARM or PowerPC. Look into the instruction sets. You will find that intel has instructions with immediate 8-bit operands for both sub and xor, ARM has them for sub, PPC has them for xor. PPC also has such instructions for sub, but then it's the wrong order - subtracting the integer from 9. In addition, I assume that an instruction with immediate operand will work faster, at least because it saves the time to store the operand in a register. However, that depends on the usage pattern.